# How do I change the white text in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've just installed vs code but when I write the code lines they are white, not colored...
How can I change the color?

That's how it looks:
[image: that'how it looks]

Comment: Please note that file type in the blue status bar is identified as "Plain Text". That normally means that you don't have an extension for that language and it's not builtin either.

Answer (score 9):

Monican your issue isn't a background or theme issue. 
You must install vuejs -> Syntax Highlight for Vue.js

I'm not a Vuejs Developer and I can't give you recommendations/ 
You should find which Vuejs extenstion / extensions will be your best friend(s).

Just open `Extension` panel and type vue.

[image: Vuejs]

Please contact me if you need an extra help.

Answer (score 4):

Press ctrl+shift+x and search for extension(for example if you have dart then search for Dart extension), if already installed then first uninstall it >> Restart VS Code >> again now install dart extension(or any programming exe. which you using currently)>> now see issue has solved.

Comment: how dart affecting vue may i ask?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install an extension that adds syntax highlighting (and other features) for `.vue` files.

You can search the extension marketplace, or click the Language indicator in the bottom right (which currently says Plain Text).

Answer (score 1):

Custom Syntax Coloring for Visual Studio Code:

On VS code, go to "Preferences" --> "Settings", on the "Search Bar" type and search "Launch", then click on "Edit in settings.json" under the Launch phrase.

Then add these codes:

```
{
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"workbench.activityBar.visible": false,
"editor.fontSize": 18,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Absent (rainglow)"


"editor.tokenColorCustomizations":
{
    "strings": "#d86464",
    "keywords": "#ff00ea",
    "comments": "#ddf129",
    "types": "#00ff6a",
    "variables": "#00c3ff",
    "functions": "#00fff2",
    "numbers": "#ae19f3",

    "textMateRules":
    [
        {
            "scope": 
            [
              ""    // This is for regular font
            ],

            "settings": 
            {
                "foreground": "#fa9c0f",  // Color assigned for regular font.
            },
        },


        {
            "scope": 
            [
              "keyword"    // This is for keyword font
            ],

            "settings": 
            {
                "foreground": "#ffffff",  // Color assigned to keyword font.
            },
        },

    ],
},
```

}

To change the regular plain white text color, change the hex color:

`"#fa9c0f"  // Color assigned for regular font.`

that should do the trick.

VS Code has to be the best IDE as of right now. You can color customize literally everything, from scroll side bars to menu settings. Syntax highlighting seriously makes a developer more productive and less error prone.

You can make the perfect custom IDE however you wish with more details from:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and add this command: `"editor.foreground": "#ff0000"` to make the text in the editor red. Zyou can also load Themes and Syntax Themes to change the text colors as well. If you are displaying line numbers with your code you can change the color of the line numbers with: `"editorLineNumber.foreground":  "#eeff00"`. These statements are added to the right-hand side of the settings display.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install extension for programming language you use, If extension is already installed then it may require "Reload". You can search extension and check whether if requires "Reload" or not. After reload the formatting will be fine.